# How can I delete anything after the space of in the cells of a whole column?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column of something that would be like XXX US, and I want to return XXX for the cell. I want to make a macro that deletes the whole column with one click. For some reason my ticker part of my code throws an error, but when i don't use a loop it works. Is there anything I can do?

```
Sub DEAS()
    Dim cellText As String
    Dim ticker As String
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 5
    Do While i < 8000

        cellText = Cells(i, 1).Value
        ticker = Left(cellText, InStr(cellText, " ") - 1)
        Cells(i, 1).Value = ticker
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub DEAS()
    Dim cellText As String
    Dim ticker As String
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 5
    Do While i < 8000
        cellText = Cells(i, 1).Value
        If InStr(cellText, " ") > 0 Then
            Cells(i, 1).Value = Split(cellText, " ")(0)
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Left(cellText, InStr(cellText, " ") - 1)` will throw an error 5 "Invalid procedure call or argument" if the `cellText` doesn't contain a space. This is most likely due to encountering a value somewhere in A5:A8000 that either isn't in the expected format or is empty.  In that case, `Instr` will return 0, which makes your call evaluate to `Left(cellText, -1)`. You need to check the return value first (note that you can also use a `For` loop - IMHO more readable when your conditions are fixed):

```
Sub DEAS()
    Dim cellText As String
    Dim ticker As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim pos As Integer

    For i = 5 To 8000
        cellText = Cells(i, 1).Value
        pos = InStr(cellText, " ")
        If pos > 0 Then
            ticker = Left(cellText, pos - 1)
            Cells(i, 1).Value = ticker
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```